# Proving this quantity is bounded due to an angle estimate

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose that $|\theta-\pi|\leq a<\pi/2$. I am trying to see why the quantity

$$\frac{1+\rho e^{i\theta}-(1+\rho^2+2\rho\cos\theta)^{1/2}}{(1+\rho^2+2\rho\cos\theta)^{1/2}\rho(\rho+2\cos\theta)}$$

stays bounded as $\rho\to0^+$. I can't see it, it is supposed to be a consequence of the estimate on $\theta$, but I just don't see why. Could anyone explain this?

PS: If anyone has a better idea for a title, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$. We know that $\frac{\pi}{2}< \pi -a \le \theta \le \pi + a < \frac{3\pi}{2}$, so $\cos \theta \le -\cos a <0$. In particular $|\rho+2\cos \theta| > \cos a >0$ as soon as $\rho < \cos a$, while $(1+\rho^2+2\rho\cos\theta)^{1/2}=|1+z| \to 1$ as $\rho \to 0^+$ so these two terms do not create problems in the denominator being bounded away from zero.

It remains to prove $\frac{1+z-|1+z|}{|z|}$ bounded when $|z|=\rho \to 0$. Multiplying with $1+z+|1+z|$ which satisfies $1<|1+z+|1+z||<3$ when $2|z|<1$ so doesn't affect boundness of the original expression, it is enough to prove:

$\frac{(1+z)^2-|1+z|^2}{|z|}$ bounded, or $\frac{z^2+2z-|z|^2-2|z|\cos \theta}{|z|}$ bounded as $|z| \to 0$.

But clearly $|\frac{z^2+2z-|z|^2-2|z|\cos \theta}{|z|}| \le 2|z|+2+ 2|\cos \theta|$ is bounded so we are done!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to be of help